# How to find nearest node given two nodes in a maze?

Tags: tree, maze

I am given a function `getNearest(int[] nodes, int src, int dest` which means:

1. nodes = array of nodes present. for eg: [4, 4, 1, 4, 13, 8, 8, 8, 0]. the starting and ending point is index and value respectively. In this array it'll be: 0 -> 4, 1 -> 4, 2 -> 1 etc...
2. src node,
3. dest node.

I need to find nearest meeting cell from `src` to `dest` in given maze `nodes`.

For eg: nodes[] = [4, 4, 1, 4, 13, 8, 8, 8, 0, 8, 14, 9, 15, 11, -1, 10, 15 ,22, 22, 22, 22, 22, 21]
src = 9, dest = 2

-1 denotes there is no edge.

The answer is 4.

What algorithm should I use for this?

I tried to use bfs for both source and destination respectively and got this output:
src's bfs = [9, 8, 11, 5, 6, 7, 0, 13, 4, 1, 3, 2]
destn's bfs = [2, 1, 4, 0, 3, 13, 8, 11, 5, 6, 7, 9]

I am not able to understand how to find the nearest node given 2 nodes in a maze by using bfs.

Is there any other algorithm I can use for this?

It is also given that each cell has multiple entry points but not more than one exit point

Comment: The BFS can maintain a counter that represents the number of steps taken. If an edge encounters a node that has already been visited, then you don't process it as the previous path must have reached the node using a shorter path. If at the end (i.e., when the queue is empty), you don't find a path, then return -1.

Comment: @KairavShah Can you give the code for that?

Comment: *"Can you give the code for that"*: please show your efforts, and focus your question on the problem you have with your attempt.